# Are there any safe source of Windows 7 desktop gadgets?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

After much painstaking searching, I haven’t been able to find any gadgets (e.g., GPU, weather, etc.) for my Windows 7 desktop. There are some gadget websites but they are riddled with adware and/or of such poor quality that they do not install/work at all.

There are a large number of people who want desktop gadgets; surely there is some alternative now that Microsoft has discontinued them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net), a wonderful, highly configurable tool that enables "gadget"-like skins.

According to the site:

> Rainmeter displays customizable skins, like memory and battery power, RSS feeds and weather forecasts, right on your desktop. Many skins are even functional: they can record your notes and to-do lists, launch your favorite applications, and control your media player - all in a clean, unobtrusive interface that you can rearrange and customize to your liking. Rainmeter is at once an application and a toolkit. You are only limited by your imagination and creativity.
>
> Rainmeter is open source software distributed free of charge under the terms of the GNU GPL v2 license.

Here is an image of my desktop, using built-in skins.  Thousands of additional suites and skins are available from web communities such as DeviantArt.

[image: Nice, if a little boring. Still - it's useful!]

Comment: Amazing... Superuser.com always comes through. Thanks.

Comment: @Zombies Remember that "mark as answer" checkbox!

Comment: Yes that is an acceptable answer, have been using it for awhile and it's quite good, certainly the best way to get widgets on windows 7 for.

Comment: @Zombies Thanks, awesome!  I'll edit it to show the default skins (which are pretty good).